# How to scrape web with python and bypass error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have around 3000 urls and some of them work while some of them don't. I tried running beautiful soup but I get some different errors, which confuses me - I'm not sure what kind of try and except block I should put in my code. What I want to do is ignore all internal sever error urls and only work with the ones that do not have errors and fetch the texts as written in the code below.

My code:

```
mega = [[]] # list in a list
for i in range(len(ab)): # ab as a dictionary with multiple keys
...     myurl = soc[i]['the_urls']
...     html = urllib2.urlopen(myurl).read()
...     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
...     row = soup.findAll('tr')
...     for r in row:
...         mega.append([r.get_text()]) # scrape all the texts
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 435, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 548, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 473, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 407, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 556, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Does the error mean that all the urls have the same problem - internal server error? In this case I guess one way I can do is to include a try and except block that says try if there is no http error 500 and pass if there is one.

Edit:

I tried to use the below code to bypass the error, I'm not sure if it is working, especially if "pass" or "continue" is doing the right thing:

```
for i in range(len(soc)):
...     myurl = soc[i]['report_url']
...     while True:
...         try:
...             html = urllib2.urlopen(myurl).read()
...             break
...         except urllib2.HTTPError:
...             continue
...     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
...     row = soup.findAll('tr')
...     for r in row:
...         mega.append([r.get_text()]) # scrape the text
```

Comment: No, it actually means that one URL returned a 500 error. You should use `try` / `except` to handle it.

Comment: Your code in the comment above is unreadable.

Comment: Your edit will loop until the call is successful. Could be forever.

Comment: @KlausD. would changing from pass to continue work?

Comment: Nope, you should remove the while loop and log the error.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the error mean that all the urls have the same problem - internal server error?

Not always. Because reason of 5XX server errors could be:

- infrastructure fails - and all pages on site will be inaccessible
- some errors on a specific page, for example, DivisionByZero while calculating that specific data

Use `try/except` to handle a problem and go to next url.

Also if you with you may make some type of statistics, and if you see many errors on some domain - guess it's not working now and move its url to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Hi, I get the sense of using try and except, but I'm not sure if my code is working - I made some edits, could you comment? Thanks.

Comment: If one of URLs is not accessible permanently you may get lock on it. You can try another way: walk through the whole list of urls, if one url is not working - move it to the end of the list and go to next url. Repeat the whole process several times == `MAX_ATTEMPS`.
Also if you have big plans on parsing data, you may look at https://scrapy.org/. It allows to write complicated grabbers very quickly. For example - https://gist.github.com/lisitsky/c4aac52edcb7abfd5975be067face1bb - parses weblancer site with 16 threads and in about several seconds returns 4k rows CSV.